# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "add_image_and_name_to_users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I'm setting up `rails_admin` in my app, I'm also using Devise, CanCanCan and Omniauth for social media logins.

My User model is the simple model that Devise sets up with a migration to add `image` and `name` to `users` (for storing basic info from Facebook)

I set `rails_admin` in the `/admin` path, and when I submit that url I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "add_image_and_name_to_users"
```

`add_image_and_name_to_users` is the name of the migration that I did to the `User` model

that migration is as follows:

```
class AddImageAndNameToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
    add_column :users, :image, :string
  end
end
```

I already did `rake db:drop` and `rake db:reset` a couple of times, but I still get the same error. This is the first time I'm working with Rails Admin (had a painful experience with ActiveAdmin), and I found this interesting thing

[image]

It thinks that `add_name_and_image_to_users` it's a standalone table

Comment: Can you post that migration?

Comment: I added the migration in question :)

Comment: When you create the migration, was a model class also created?

Comment: Nop, he just adds the column to the users table. It's working fine in the rest of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, I added to the `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

`config.included_models = ["Class1", "Class2", "Class3"]`, to whitelist only the models I was interested in.